# instant notification for user online - offline status

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make online/offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435638/how-to-make-online-offline)

I want to make a script display online - offline status to other users using php .

For example: Let there be two user in our database . First user is online and second user is offline. When second user will be online, how can first user get an immediate notification that the second user is online, without refreshing page or refreshing div tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) for this.

Comment: sorry for late response , i have resolved this issue...